# Can't load CSS in MVC project

Tags: css, eclipse, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-security

I created a WebProject with MVC, so first I added servlet configurations with views and controllers, and all styles worked fine. But when I implemented SpringSecurity to create the login page, all css, js and img stop working...

My project structure:

[image]

web.xml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

  <display-name>gesto</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
          </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fihoca.gespro2.controllers" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

As you can see, I mapped the resources like MVC tutorials do.

spring-security.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <form-login default-target-url="/home" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/index" />
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="Secret123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

And these are my links to css and js in JSP pages:

```
<script src="/resources/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The solution was change the href to this:

```
<script src="resources/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
```

Basically, I deleted the first "/" and it worked.